# Changing contents of a combo menu depending on previous input

Tags: html, css, combobox

So I would like a combo box which displays different times, depending on what the user chose in previous combo boxes.

To give an example, if a user chose "matinee times" then the next combo box will have matinee times only. However if the user chose "evening times" then the user will only have evening times displayed in the next combo box.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can drive your select boxes with an object that contains arrays. This makes it easy to add/remove times.

```js
var times = {
  "evening": ["7:00", "8:00", "9:30", "10:30", "11:30"],
  "morning": ["10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:15"]
}

$("#group").change(function(ev) {
  var group = ev.currentTarget.value;
  // Clear out the existing values
  $("#times").empty();
  // If they didn't go back to select, load the new values
  if (group !== "select") {
    // For each value in the group, add an option
    times[group].forEach(function(value) {
      $("#times").append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", value)
        .text(value));
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="group">
  <option value="select">Select...</option>
  <option value="morning">Morning</option>
  <option value="evening">Evening</option>
</select>

<select id="times"></select>
```